$H:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous map from top space $M$. Show that $H^{-1}(e)$ divides $M$ where $e\in \text{int}(H(M))$
Let $M$ be a topological space and $H:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and surjective. Suppose   $e\in \text{int}(H(M))$. Then show $H^{-1}(e)$ divides $M$; that is, $M\setminus H^{-1}(e)$ has at least two components.[1]
The following is my proof. I'd appreciate your feedback about its correctness or if it could be improved.
Since $H$ is surjective, we have $H(M)=\mathbb{R}$. Also $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{e\}$ splits into open sets $A=(-\infty,e)$ and $B=(e,\infty)$. So $M$ is the union of three disjoint sets $M=H^{-1}(A)\cup H^{-1}(e) \cup H^{-1}(B)$. So $M\setminus H^{-1}(e)$ is the union of disjoint open sets $H^{-1}(A)$ and $H^{-1}(B)$ which means it's disconnected and has at least two components.
[1] Abraham, Ralph, and Jerrold E. Marsden. Foundations of mechanics. No. 364. American Mathematical Soc., 2008.

All that is missing is a statement that $H^{-1}(A)$ and $H^{-1}(B)$ are nonempty.

@arkeet Thanks. Can we say that it's implied since $H$ is surjective? No matter what we choose for $e$, the preimage of $A$ and $B$ will be nonempty.

Yes, it follows easily from $H$ being surjective (and $A,B$ nonempty). But this is the part where it is used that $H$ is surjective.
Actually $H$ doesn't need to be surjective, because as long as $e \in \operatorname{int}(H(M))$, the image of $H$ will intersect both $A$ and $B$.
